# SCPI Commands VB.net displaying values within a loop

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, gpib

I am sending SCPI commands via GPIB-USB to a signal generator. I am sending a command to change the frequency, and this command is looped so that the frequency keeps on changing until the loop completes. This is successful. I am also sending a command to read the frequency. I want to be able to read the frequency at each step.

I am using this as a reference for reading and writing from a signal generator. https://www.keysight.com/main/editorial.jspx?ckey=492255&id=492255&nid=-536900124.0.08&lc=fin&cc=FI

The problem I have is that the frequency does not get displayed to my text box until I finish the loop. Then, I see the last frequency, which is 500. I inserted a breakpoint in visual studio and I did see that the frequency value is changing, but my textbox which is supposed to display the value does not update properly. The values on the signal generator are also changing. I even tried just displaying F instead of the value from my sig gen. My program just does not want to display the frequency in the textbox I created until the loop completes. 
Why can't I read each frequency, step by step? How can I fix this problem?

```
Dim F As Integer
Dim Frequency As Integer
Dim dblData As Double
Dim strReply As String

For F = 30 To 500 'MHz 30 to 500
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100) 'delay of 100 ms
    Frequency = F
    instrument.WriteString("FREQ" & Str$(F) & "MHZ") 'send SCPI command, with F being converted to string
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    instrument.WriteString("FREQ?") 'ask signal generator what frequency is
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    strReply = instrument.ReadString()
    dblData = Val(strReply)
    SigGenFreqValueLabel.Text = dblData 'display frequency from signal generator in text box
    Console.WriteLine("Frequency" & F) 'Testing if this portion of the for loop is reached
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:
I inserted Application.DoEvents() below SigGenFreqValueLabel.Text = dblData